# Fix SyntaxError on ScriptTransformer.js updating from jest 23.6 to 24.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

Updated jest from 23.6 to 24.1 with yarn. Get SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier import Whatever

I tried updating every node module that I guess could be related.

```
-    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
-    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
+    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
+    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
     "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.24",
@@ -138,8 +138,7 @@
     "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
     "@types/react-transition-group": "^2.0.14",
     "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.15.0",
-    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
-    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
+    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
     "babel-merge": "^2.0.1",
     "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.9.0",
     "babel-plugin-dual-import": "^1.2.1",
@@ -152,7 +151,7 @@
     "expect": "^1.20.2",
     "fake-indexeddb": "^2.0.3",
     "haml": "~0.4.3",
-    "jest": "^23.6.0",
+    "jest": "^24.1.0",
     "jest-junit": "^5.1.0",
     "jest-styled-components": "6.3.1",
     "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
@@ -166,8 +165,8 @@
     "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.3.2",
     "synchronous-promise": "^2.0.6",
     "thread-loader": "^1.1.5",
-    "ts-jest": "^23.10.4",
-    "typescript": "^3.1.3",
+    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
+    "typescript": "^3.3.3",
```

Should run `yarn test` as before.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

The problem was in jest.config.js
We had node_modules declared after our internal modules:

```
'moduleDirectories': ['our_modules', 'node_modules']
```

with the new version this no longer works.

Comment: Jorge, can you clarify what you mean by 'this no longer works'? Do we have to always put `node_modules` last?